# wp_footer hook not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a plugin to add image at bottom right corner of every page. Followin is the code which is functioning correct and add image as content.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'scroll_to_top_data');
```

but I want to add it after footer on bottom right corner for which I tried:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'scroll_to_top_data');
```

but this is not displaying image anywhere also no error is displayed. I'm using twentyfifteen theme but of course I want this plugin to be usable on all theme of wordpress. Please guide me why it's not working with wp_footer hook and how can I put this on after footer? Below is the scroll_to_top_data function

```
function scroll_to_top_data($content = NULL) {
$post_id = get_the_ID();
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'scroll';

$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = 1");
$beforeafter = $myrows[0]->beforeafter;
$where_like = $myrows[0]->where_like;
$status = $myrows[0]->status;
$image = $myrows[0]->image;
$action = $myrows[0]->action;
$color = $myrows[0]->color;
$display = $myrows[0]->display;
$except_ids = $myrows[0]->except_ids;
$url = $myrows[0]->url;
$width = $myrows[0]->width;
$position = $myrows[0]->position;
$str = $image;

if ($status != 0) {
    $scrollImage = '<img src="' . $image . '"';
    return $content . $scrollImage;
} else {
    return $content;
}
}
```

Comment: What does the `scroll_to_top_data` function look like?

Comment: #Jesse I've updated my question, pleae check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_footer` action doesn't pass any parameters or expect any return value like a filter would (in this case the `$content`). Filters expect to pass information in to be modified and returned, actions do not. To get your image to output you have to change the following:

```
if ($status != 0) {
    $scrollImage = '<img src="' . $image . '"';
    return $content . $scrollImage;
} else {
    return $content;
}
```

To actually echo the image:

```
if ($status != 0) {
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />'; //doesn't seem to have a closing bracket?
}
```

Rather than trying to append it to the existing content.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that your scroll_to_top_data is never called especially if you have it in your plugin's constructor. You will need to change it to
add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'scroll_to_top_data'));

Take a look at this SO post:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes